# How to show a MessageBox from a static method in C# ion WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, static-methods, messagebox

I have a Page on Windows Phone that is called asynchronously, from which I want to show a MessageBox. I would normally:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("The message"));
```

but this doesn't quite work in a static method.

How do I get the MessageBox to display from a static method?

Answer (score 4):

You can access the UI dispatcher using `Application.Current.RootVisual.Dispatcher`:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = Application.Current.RootVisual.Dispatcher;
dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("The message"));
```